# how to have both string placeholder surrounded with quotes inside a string in python?

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

i have xpath that looks like this:

```
"//*[@id="comments_408947"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]"
```

the comment_408947 must be wrapped up with quotes as well as the entire xpath.

i have the number 408947 as a string and need to add it after 'comments_'

```
    com_id = '408947'
    query= f("//*[@id=comments_" + """%s""" + "]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]", com_id)
```

but it's not working.

Comment: Have you tries scaping the quotes `print("Hello\"world")` will print `Hello"world`. Another option is to use single quotes and double quotes: `print('Hello"world')` would print the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use triple quotes, it will solve the issue for you or you need to escape the inner `"`, otherwise it is interpreted as a string endpoint.,

```
'''//*[@id="comments_408947"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]'''
```

Answer (score 1):

`"//*[@id="comments_408947"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]"` is invalid - you need to use different quotes to allow `"` as *inside* characters - or you need to escape them:

```
'''"//*[@id="comments_408947"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]"''' # works - uses ''' as delim
# too complex for string coloring here on SO but works:
""""//*[@id="comments_408947"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]"""" # works - uses """ as delim
"//*[@id=\"comments_408947\"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]"     # works - escapes "
'//*[@id=\"comments_408947\"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]'     # works - uses ' as delim
```

the same goes for your id-insertion -you can use string interpolation:

```
com_id = '408947'
query= f'''//*[@id="comments_{com_id}"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]''', com_id)
```